# Explaining refraction of light through a glass slab

Tags: refraction, glass

Let's consider a glass slab ABCD.
Now a light ray is incident on the near end of the air-glass interface AB and is emerging from the glass-air interface BD. In such a manner:
[image: refraction of light]

Is there something wrong how I have made my figure. Can light emerge in such a manner from a glass slab.

This is my first question and English is not my first language I hope you understood my doubt. I feel like the figure I have drawn does not look like the conventional ray diagram of light entering a glass slab.

Also I am not an expert I am just a student who wants to know the answer to my question.

Comment: Schematics are perfectly fine, except that if surface is not covered with anti-reflection coating - there will be reflected rays also - from AB and BD.

Answer (score 1):

There is a potential problem.

The critical angle $c = \sin^{-1}\left ( \frac 1 n\right)$, where $n$ is the refractive index of the glass.

At the first interface $r\le c$ and at the second interface $i_2 \le c$ for there to be refraction

However, $i_2 + r= 90^\circ$, and so only if $n\le 1/\sqrt 2$, is refraction at both interfaces possible.

As a numerical example, if $n=1.5$ then $c\approx 42^\circ$ and smallest that $i_2$ can be is $90-42 = 48^\circ$ which is greater than the critical angle and total internal reflection will occur at the second interface, but if $n=1.35$ then $c \approx 48^\circ$ and refraction can occur at both interfaces.