# $r_1+r_2= A$ in prisms

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, visible-light, geometric-optics, geometry

In class we derived a result which said that the sum of the 2 angles of refraction in a triangular prism $r_1+r_2$ is equal to the angle of the prism $A$. The proof goes like this

[image]

Over here, it is easy to see from the triangle LMN, that $r_1+r_2= A$.
However, what if the rays pass through the prism like this

[image]

Over here, from the triangle ABC, we can clearly see that $r_1+r_2$ is not equal to $A$. In order to clear this doubt I went on PHET labs, and used their simulations to better understand what happens to  the light when it enters the prism but I saw that my diagram was not physically feasible. Every time, I tried  to get something similar to my diagram, it would end up in total internal reflection.

So my question is- Is my diagram physically possible (for any refractive index and angle of prism). If no (which is more likely), then why? If yes (which is less likely), then what happens to the general result stating that $r_1+r_2=A$?

Link for the simulation- https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/bending-light/latest/bending-light_all.html

EDIT- I have found a case similar to my diagram. Now, the only problem I have is that $r_1 +r_2$ is not equal to $A$. But this should not be happening as $r_1 +r_2 = A$ is a general result right?
[image]

Comment: @Thomas Fritsch I really appreciate the efforts put in to edit my question. But it really is r1 and r2 not gamma. r stands for angle of refraction

Comment: oh sorry. I have read it as $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ in your drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this yourself and remember that the critical angle is related to refractive index.

Using the Phet simulation set up the arrangement as shown in the left-hand diagram with normal incidence, the environment set to air and the object set to glass.

[image]

The angle of incidence on the second interface $x=A$.
Move the object slider toward air and observe what happens.

With the setup in the right-hand diagram the value of $y$ will be greater than $x$.
Again start with the object slider at glass and move it towards air and observe what happens.

A related post is [Explaining refraction of light through a glass slab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/780233/explaining-refraction-of-light-through-a-glass-slab/780261#780261).

Comment: Yes, I finally manged to replicate my diagram in the simulation.  However, my original doubts still persists. r1+r2 is not equal to A, in my diagram, but it is taught as a general result to us. Do you think I should edit my question?

Comment: In your second diagram $r_2-r_1=A$.

Comment: Yes. But that should not happen right?

Comment: There is significant difference because the incident ray enters the prism “above” the normal.

Comment: But then why is r1+r2=A considered as a general result? Infact, it is after using this result that my teacher derived another result- the angle of deviation in a prism is   equal to i+e-A, which is also considered a  general result. My doubt is that if these results are general results, then they should work for every case. Otherwise they should not be called general results right?

Comment: So you are right, it is only the rule for light not reflected inside the prism, so not really "general" but still right for all the experiments one does usually with prisms.

Comment: @trula Please look at my latest comment under your answer. I really still don't understand why my diagram must be wrong in all cases.

Comment: @Farcher I have reallly thoight about your comment and I have come to the conclusion that indeed the problem comes  from the fact that the ray is incident above the normal which means that the refracting ray emerges from below the normal. I have concluded that when  the ray is incident above the normal, it will either show TIR or pass through the prism as shown in my diagram and not as shown in the diagram above it (the standard diagram).  Is my conclusion valid?

Comment: @Pumpkin_Star You are correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Even though I am still a bit doubtful as my textbook does not talk about this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is a general rule, if you have no total reflection. If some simulation gives you a different result it is wrong, in your picture there would be total reflection with any  refraction index. Why do you not believe in the calculation you did in class? Than you should have a different calculation?

Comment: According to the calculations from my diagram, A=r2-r1. This means that r2 should be should be greater than A. Also we should be taking in consideration that  r1 can not be more than 90-A or else it will never hit the right side of the prism. Now, let A be 30 degrees, R1 be 10 degrees then r2 will be 40 degrees, which is the critical angle for a medium having around 1.55 refractive index. So if I have a refractive index around 1.4 then my diagram can be applicable right?

Comment: 30° incoming and 10° in the medium means n=2,9 not 1,44+ you really should do the calculation and not just take any angles!

Comment: 30 is not the angle of incidence. It is the value of A or angle of prism. The angle of incidence can be any value that gives r1 as 10.